# Partial for controller - how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry at first if it's a newbie question, I try to find a correct way to code it :

I need to re-use a view AND it's logic in a few places in my App

This view has some javascript, I will use "render" to display it (ajax and innerHTML are not relevant), but I don't want to repeat my logic in each controller using it, so : is their a "partial" way to do it in  my controller ?
A controller "partial" way to inject code ?

the only solution I have for the moment is copy/past the controller code, and I don't want to do it

regards

gregoire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a parent class to contain all the duplicated controller code. A simple approach is to use `ApplicationController`, with all methods then available to its descendants.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def say_hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

class Subcontroller < ApplicationController
  def index
    say_hello # => Hello
  end
end
```

This is a simple approach, though a `presenter`, `decorator` or `service` object might be more appropriate. Have a search and see what suits your needs, or I can give more input if you expand the question a little.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't think about it but it make sense, thank you and I will read about those otheir paterns